# How to write subselect method for linq to entity query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, extension-methods

I have this linq to entity query:

```
var query = (
       from x in ctx.Applications
       from t2 in ctx.Calendar
                  .Where(t2 => t2.Date >= SqlFunctions.DateAdd("dd", x.AllTime, x.RegDate) && t2.FreeDay == false)
                  .OrderBy(t2 => t2.Date)
                  .Take(1)
                  .DefaultIfEmpty()
       select(new ApplicationGridView 
       { 
          ...
          HavePartners = x.HavePartners,
          PlanningEndDate = t2.Date
       });
```

How to write an extension method or method with part select (for using in diferrent selects), something like this:

```
public IQueryable<Calendar> GetNextDate(DateTime? dateFrom, int? interval)
{
    return ctx.Calendar
           .Where(t2 => t2.Date >= SqlFunctions.DateAdd("dd", interval, dateFrom) && t2.FreeDay == false)
           .OrderBy(t2 => t2.Date)
           .Take(1)
           .DefaultIfEmpty();
}
```

And then use in select:

```
var query = (
           from x in ctx.Applications
           from t2 in GetNextDate(x.RegDate, x.AllTime)
           select(new ApplicationGridView 
           { 
              ...
              HavePartners = x.HavePartners,
              PlanningEndDate = t2.Date
           });

var result = query.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but i'll try; A subselect is usually a select after the first select is done. You can do that on the "var result", before you ToList() it... ? If i am far out in my answer, maybe re-write the question and make it clearer would be a good idea...

Comment: Why does your decision (GetNextDate method) not work? (Except that you have to pass "ctx" as an argument, of course).

Comment: In this example i get exception. Also I try pass ctx, create extension for ctx, also for Calendar entity, but always executing return error: EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Models.Calendar] GetNextDate(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @Bjørn's suggestion is appropriate. However if you do not want one additional query to the database, please check the following decision.

First, introduce class

```
    private class MyJoin<T> {
        public T A { get; set; }
        public Calendar B { get; set; }
    }
```

Second, write a method like

```
    private IQueryable<MyJoin<T>> Prepare<T>(IQueryable<MyJoin<T>> myJoin, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<MyJoin<T>, bool>> clause) {
        return myJoin
            .Where(clause)
            .OrderBy(x=> x.B.Date)
            .Take(1)
            .DefaultIfEmpty();
    }
```

Third, use it as following

```
        var query = Prepare((from x1 in ctx.Applications
           from x2 in ctx.Calendar
           select(new MyJoin {
               A = x1,
               B = x2,
           })), x => x.B.Date >= SqlFunctions.DateAdd("dd", x.A.AllTime, x.A.RegDate) && x.B.FreeDay == false)
           .Select(x => new { 
              HavePartners = x.A.HavePartners,
              PlanningEndDate = x.B.Date
           });
        var result = query.Where(x => true /* Your condition */).ToList();
```

Finally, you could rewrite the `Prepare` method as an extension method to get access to the simplier syntax.

Does this simplify your task? Note that I have used other classes, thus correct any obvious syntax or typing mistakes.

**Update**. I have updated the answer to move the "where"-clause to the method's signature.